# J2ME-WebService

Tags: web-services, exception, soap, java-me, midlet

I am working on J2ME-WEBSERVICES to get information from server through SOAP protocol. For this task actually i went through two ways,

1. i) First created Web-service with normal java class in elipse and then created Client project for the web-service then it creates stub and service classes.

   ii) And then i deploy the war file in to tomcat server and i successfully used the java class method got result correctly,

   iii) URL i have used in Android application, With KSOAP api application works correctly, even i tested in mobile.

   iv) but when i
   used the same url in j2me-midlet
   code i was written like:

   ```
   SoapObject soap=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
   soap.addProperty("barcode", barnum);
   HttpTransport se=new HttpTransport();
   se.setUrl(URL);
   se.setSoapAction(SOAP_ACTION);
   se.call(soap);
   ```

   but i am getting Nullpointer
   exception when pointer at
   `SoapWriter.writeProperty()` class.
2. Second way is,

   i) I used the stub and
   service classes of
   `WebserviceClient` project, and i
   created a MIDlet in same package
   (placed all supported jar files for
   MIDlet in lib folder)

   ```
   DBWEBSoapBindingStub stub=new DBWEBSoapBindingStub();
   DBWEBService service=(DBWEBService)stub;
   stub._setProperty(Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "URL of webservice at server");
   String result=stub.getBarcodeDetails(barcode);
   ```

   ii) I successfully compiled and
   preverified, with the generated
   class files i created jar, and when
   i deploy application in mobile,
   getting below exceptions ::

   - Noclassfound exception for `org.apache.axis.client.stub :` For this i placed axis.jar file in to application jar file. but still problem is when i deploy in to mobile, " jar file is max size" problem (size==1.6MB)
   - second exception is `javax.xml.rpc.Service` class not found : if i place the jar file in my application jar file it gives me exception like : " cannot create a class in system package "

so please let me know the solution for this issue, hope experts can help me out.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a WSDL client library that is compatible with J2ME. Axis library used by Eclipse wizards definitely isn't.

I recommend that you use Netbeans that can create a client automatically for you. See this [article](http://nandokakimoto.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/creating-a-j2me-web-service-client/).